# Send DataSMS exceeding the SMS size limit. Android

Tags: java, android, sms, port

I am trying to send an SMS from an android device (sender) to an J2ME device (receiver).

I have to send the information through  a specific port, so Android offers me the `sendDataMessage` method which sends the information as bytes and allows to add an specific port.

All works fine for SMS smaller than the limit size.
But if I use this method for SMS with information that exceeds the limit size (133bytes per SMS, I think) the following error appears:

[image]

Take a look just in the `MediatekClassFactory` and `MaliEGL` labels.

I use this code to configure and send the SMS:

> ```
> SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
> ```
>
> String Numero_SMS=configuracao.getNumeroSMS();
>       short Porto_SMS=Short.parseShort(configuracao.getPortoSMS());
>   smsManager.sendDataMessage(Numero_SMS, null, Porto_SMS, mensaje.getBytes(), null,null);

So, I can not use the `sendMultipartTextMessage` method because that doesn't allow me to especify a port number.

Any idea for sending longer SMS especifying the port number?

Thank you,

Comment: Have you considered MMS?

Comment: Not possible, the J2ME receiver doesnt support MMS.

Comment: Even if you could send a longer SMS message from the phone (unlikely) it probably wouldn't be acceptable to the SMS servers. But there must be a format to indicate 2 or more messages belong to the same send.

Comment: CSMS - concatenated SMS ?

Comment: Yes, I had developed an J2ME application for the sender which allows sending SMS as long as you want and it did the hole process automatically, without dividing the SMS in smaller peaces neither sending the SMS as byte content. So, J2ME sending was so easy. I have read something about CSMS but i didn't found any android and/or J2ME example. Do you know something about that? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of any examples.